# JAXB "nor any of its super class is known to this context" avoid @XmlSeeAlso

Tags: java, jaxb, jax-rs, java-ee-6

## Explanation & Workaround

Currently I am using JAX-RS and letting JAXB bindings automatically handle converting the data to XML and JSON for me in a JEE6 project.  Everything is working absolutely fantastically until I try to create a generic response object to wrap all of my information in.

When I attempt to use my generic response class `com.eln00b.Wrapper` (which contains a `private Object result` attribute within it) I get:

> javax.xml.bind.MarshalException - with linked exception: [com.sun.istack.SAXException2: class com.eln00b.CustomObject nor any of its super class is known to this context. javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: class com.eln00b.CustomObject nor any of its super class is known to this context.]

So I add to `com.eln00b.Wrapper`:

```
@XmlSeeAlso ({com.eln00b.CustomObject})
public class Wrapper {
}
```

Everything works fine.

## The Problem

I want this to be extremely generic.  I do not want t constantly add classes to the `@XmlSeeAlso` annotation on the `com.eln00b.Wrapper` class.  **How do I have the system automatically locate all of my classes for the JAXB context?**

Even if it's a hack where I use something like [Reflections](https://code.google.com/p/reflections/) to load the data, that's fine.  I'm just not sure how to get the context to load all of that data without the `@XmlSeeAlso` annotation.  With the large amount of annotations I will be creating it will just simply not work.

## How It Worked Manually

It worked manually just by adding the data like so doing manual conversions.  However, I do **not** want to use manual XML/JSON creation unless I absolutely need to (I don't want to deal with content negotiation or anything like that).

Sample:

```
JAXBContext.newInstance(new Class[] {Wrapper.class, CustomObject.class});
```

Comment: The catch-all technique would be to create the JAXBContext from a colon separated list of packages, one or more could contain all those classes. Clearly, *some* hint has to be given to context creation - otherwise the boundary of the expanding universe would be the limit ;-)

Comment: @laune That would be fine, but how do I tell the EE6 container which `JAXBContext` to use?  Is it just as simple as creating an `@Provider`?

Comment: I've found this in the JAX-RS documentation: "However, if the default JAXBContext class is not suitable, then you can supply a JAXBContext class for the application using a JAX-RS ContextResolver provider interface." I'd have to dig in wehre you probably know more than I to get any closer. Sorry.

Comment: @laune I didn't see that in the documentation.  I'll have to look into it and see what's up.  When I get it working (or if not) I will post the results here.

Comment: Section: "Using JAX-RS With JAXB" http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gkknj.html

Comment: This is working right now:  https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform_Common_Criteria_Certification/5/html/RESTEasy_Reference_Guide/Pluggable_JAXBContext_s_with_ContextResolvers.html   Just need to put together a publish-friendly example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So here is what the essence of the custom resolver looks like:

```
@Provider
@Produces ({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
public class JaxbContextResolver implements ContextResolver<JAXBContext> {

  @Override
  public JAXBContext getContext(Class<?> type) {
    // load appropriate context data
    Class[] bindTypes = ...

    // create 
    try {
      return JAXBContext.newInstance(bindTypes);
    } catch (JAXBException e) {
      // todo:  this can be handled better but works for the example
      throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
  }
}
```

Now, the processing for "*load appropriate context data*" is pretty simple.  By basically mimicking `@XmlSeeAlso` using runtime data:

1. Create a custom something (annotation, processing method, whatever) that marks a particular field/method as "contextual"
2. Load the field/method data pulling the data types out
3. Make sure you do not load duplicates and check for infinite recursion possibilities

Now, I used some caching to help make things more efficient for myself.  I also created a slightly more complex setup for my root object where it actually kept track of the class data on its own and made it pretty speedy.  I also created an alternative that marked classes as "contextual" that I used package inspection to load via annotations and just automatically add to the context but I have not checked efficiency on that yet.  I have some ideas for a 3rd implementation, but I want to get more benchmarking completed.

Comment: It's ok if you load duplicates, jaxbContext will only hold a reference once. Make sure that the getContext method is only called once, it's a very expensive operation. Log a warn message or something

Comment: @cocorossello That's actually exactly what I did.  The initial run I just let it be called multiple times and (while expensive) wasn't terrible.  When I did a load test is when it became noticeable.  After that I switched the handling and made sure it was only called once.  Everything behaved tremendously better.